# Error en enrutamiento web con Laravel y vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

estoy intentando crear un vista y conectar mi api para traer datos, pero me arroja  un 404, al verificar en las devtools de chrome, me dice que no encuentra la ruta API, y al parecer esta ligada bien, espero puedan ayudarme, no logro ver el problema

Inicialmente con un botón me lleva a la siguiente ruta, estoy creando la vista activado

**Boton**:
*http://localhost:8000/group/1/activate*

El arhivo **web.php** recibe mi ruta y llama al controlador para cargar la vista:

```
Route::get('/group/{id}/activate','GroupController@activateUser');
```

Todo bien enseguida me muestra la vista, el problema viene aquí, donde intento llamar a la API para traer datos;

```
axios.get('activates', { //Aqui llamo a la **API.php**
```

Este es mi **Api.php** donde intento acceder al controlador y traer los datos

```
Route::get('/activates', 'API\GroupController@getInactives')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Y este es el error que me presenta en chrome;

http://localhost:8000/group/1/activates **Not Found**

```
Response:
{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"
file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\kiubix\\autonomus\\e-learning-autonomos\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php"
line: 179
message: ""
trace:
```

Answer (score 1):

*Encontré mi error, no era más que añadir '**api/**' y la ruta de mi petición adicional con un '**/**' y después mis filtros, solo corregí la petición axios:*

```
axios.get('/api/activates/', {
```

Ya me retorna los valores